# Performance of cudaMalloc3D instead of cudaMallocPitch for 2D objects

Tags: cuda

I have a code which needs both 2D and 3D objects (in addition to ordinary 1D arrays). Should I use `cudaMallocPitch` for 2D objects and `cudaMalloc3D` for 3D objects, or could I use `cudaMalloc3D` for both? Is there any performance benefit of using `cudaMallocPitch` for 2D over `cudaMalloc3D`?

Comment: The programming guide contains examples on how using pitched 2d and 3d allocations. You may wish to construct an example out of them and compare the performance. The two kernel function should perform the same operations for a fair comparison.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested in the comment above, I have constructed an example out of the code snippets contained in the Programming Guide. The code is reported below. In the code, I'm using `cudaMallocPitch` and `cudaMalloc3D` for 2D objects.

For the moment, I have run the algorithm on my laptop card (GeForce GT 540M) and, for a `256x256` object, the timing is approximately the same, with only a slight increase for `cudaMalloc3D`. The timing has been about `24ms` for `cudaMallocPitch` and `24.5ms`/`25ms` for `cudaMalloc3D`.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<cuda.h>
#include<cuda_runtime.h>
#include<device_launch_parameters.h>
#include<conio.h>

#define BLOCKSIZE_x 16
#define BLOCKSIZE_y 16

#define N 256
#define M 256

/*****************/
/* CUDA MEMCHECK */
/*****************/
#define gpuErrchk(ans) { gpuAssert((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }
inline void gpuAssert(cudaError_t code, char *file, int line, bool abort=true)
{
    if (code != cudaSuccess) 
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"GPUassert: %s %s %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(code), file, line);
        if (abort) { getch(); exit(code); }
    }
}

/*******************/
/* iDivUp FUNCTION */
/*******************/
int iDivUp(int a, int b){ return ((a % b) != 0) ? (a / b + 1) : (a / b); }

/******************/
/* TEST KERNEL 2D */
/******************/
__global__ void test_kernel_2D(float* d_a, size_t pitch)
{

    int tidx =  blockIdx.x*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x;
    int tidy =  blockIdx.y*blockDim.y+threadIdx.y;

    if ((tidx<M) && (tidy<N)) {
        float* row_a = (float*)((char*)d_a + tidx*pitch);
        row_a[tidy] = row_a[tidy] * row_a[tidy];
    }
}

/******************/
/* TEST KERNEL 3D */
/******************/
__global__ void test_kernel_3D(cudaPitchedPtr devPitchedPtr)
{

    int tidx =  blockIdx.x*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x;
    int tidy =  blockIdx.y*blockDim.y+threadIdx.y;

    char* devPtr = (char*)devPitchedPtr.ptr;

    if ((tidx<M) && (tidy<N)) {
        float* row = (float*)(devPtr + tidx*devPitchedPtr.pitch);
        row[tidy] = row[tidy] * row[tidy];
    }

}

/********/
/* MAIN */
/********/
int main()
{
    float a[N][M];
    float *d_a;

    size_t pitch;

    for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
        for (int j=0; j<M; j++) {
            a[i][j] = 3.f;
            //printf("row %i column %i value %f \n",i,j,a[i][j]);
        }

    float time;
    cudaEvent_t start, stop;

    // --- 2D pitched allocation and host->device memcopy
    cudaEventCreate(&start);
    cudaEventCreate(&stop);
    cudaEventRecord(start, 0);

    gpuErrchk(cudaMallocPitch(&d_a,&pitch,M*sizeof(float),N));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy2D(d_a,pitch,a,M*sizeof(float),M*sizeof(float),N,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

    dim3 GridSize1(iDivUp(M,BLOCKSIZE_x),iDivUp(N,BLOCKSIZE_y));
    dim3 BlockSize1(BLOCKSIZE_y,BLOCKSIZE_x);
    test_kernel_2D<<<GridSize1,BlockSize1>>>(d_a,pitch);
    gpuErrchk(cudaPeekAtLastError());
    gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceSynchronize());

    cudaEventRecord(stop, 0);
    cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
    cudaEventElapsedTime(&time, start, stop);
    printf("Elapsed time 2D:  %3.1f ms \n", time);

   //gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy2D(a,M*sizeof(float),d_a,pitch,M*sizeof(float),N,cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    //for (int i=0; i<N; i++) for (int j=0; j<M; j++) printf("row %i column %i value %f\n",i,j,a[i][j]);

    // --- 3D pitched allocation and host->device memcopy
    cudaEventCreate(&start);
    cudaEventCreate(&stop);
    cudaEventRecord(start, 0);

    cudaExtent extent = make_cudaExtent(M * sizeof(float), N, 1);

    cudaPitchedPtr devPitchedPtr;
    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc3D(&devPitchedPtr, extent));

    cudaMemcpy3DParms p = { 0 };
    p.srcPtr.ptr = a;
    p.srcPtr.pitch = M * sizeof(float);
    p.srcPtr.xsize = M;
    p.srcPtr.ysize = N;
    p.dstPtr.ptr = devPitchedPtr.ptr;
    p.dstPtr.pitch = devPitchedPtr.pitch;
    p.dstPtr.xsize = M;
    p.dstPtr.ysize = N;
    p.extent.width = M * sizeof(float);
    p.extent.height = N;
    p.extent.depth = 1;
    p.kind = cudaMemcpyHostToDevice;
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy3D(&p));

    dim3 GridSize2(iDivUp(M,BLOCKSIZE_x),iDivUp(N,BLOCKSIZE_y));
    dim3 BlockSize2(BLOCKSIZE_y,BLOCKSIZE_x);
    test_kernel_3D<<<GridSize2,BlockSize2>>>(devPitchedPtr);
    gpuErrchk(cudaPeekAtLastError());
    gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceSynchronize());

    cudaEventRecord(stop, 0);
    cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
    cudaEventElapsedTime(&time, start, stop);
    printf("Elapsed time 2D:  %3.1f ms \n", time);

    p.srcPtr.ptr = devPitchedPtr.ptr;
    p.srcPtr.pitch = devPitchedPtr.pitch;
    p.dstPtr.ptr = a;
    p.dstPtr.pitch = M * sizeof(float); 
    p.kind = cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost;
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy3D(&p));

    //for (int i=0; i<N; i++) for (int j=0; j<M; j++) printf("row %i column %i value %f\n",i,j,a[i][j]);

    getch();
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: I tested your code on even slower card (GT 520) and `cudaMallocPitch` is actually slightly slower, but after increasing the problem size (`N` and `M`), `cudaMalloc3D` becomes slower.